# DataGrid with binded ObservableCollection overrided OnCollectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

I have WPF DataGrid binded to ObservableCollection. When user clicks to datagrid, type text and press enter he adds new line and I need to get this line and execute some code.

```
    public class WatchListData<Quote>: ObservableCollection<Quote>
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        MessageBox.Show(e.Action.ToString());
    }
 }
```

The problem is that it fires when user start typing but not when user finished typed and pressed enter. So I can't get what user typed. Also only ".Add" Action types fires, but I need to catch when user changed existing row too. Please guide me what can I do.

Comment: you can try to capture the event OnKeyPressed and check for the enter key.

Comment: @sexta13 Editing cell can be completed just by clicking to another cell or window. I need to capture any update of cell

Comment: then you can have two events for that: OnKeyPressed and LostFocus

Comment: @sexta13 That would be low level approach, I wouldn't need binding and Observable collection. I want to do it in MVVM style, not touching datagrid.

Comment: ok. still, you can have eventToCommand with MVVM light (for example).
Anyway, when the user clicks on other cell or window you can have the OnCollectionChanged. But for the enter key, I think you will have to use something like OnKeyPressed and check for the Enter Key. That can all be done in the ViewModel, with the EventToCommand

Comment: @sexta13 I think I can do it from underlying class Quote which has two properties Symbol in Last. I can write my logic in the setter of each property

Comment: @sexta13 no bad idea, I will not know what was before in this cell